# How to pass class instance to LowLevelMouseProc?

Tags: c++, winapi, hook, instance

I am implementing logic to handle global mouse clicks and I stuck at moment where I need to get data from [LowLevelMouseProc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644986%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). Currently, I am setting global variable at point when I am creating instance of MyClass and I able to access it from LowLevelMouseProc, but I suppose that isn't right approach.

Setting hook:

```
g_myClass = this;
SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE_LL, MyClass::MouseHookProc, LoadLibraryA("user32.dll"), 0);
```

LowLevelMouseProc:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK MyClass::MouseHookProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    MOUSEHOOKSTRUCT * pMouseStruct = (MOUSEHOOKSTRUCT *)lParam;
    g_myClass.onClick(wParam, pMouseStruct->pt.x, pMouseStruct->pt.y); //isn't good
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The low level mouse hook offers no mechanism by which you can retrieve an instance pointer. Using a global variable is often the best option.

If you cannot make your program work that way you will need to use a thunk. That technique has been discussed in many places and a web search will provide more detail. For instance a cursory search on my part yielded this: http://zabkat.com/blog/hook-callback-thunk-x64.htm

Comment: I think I can go with global variable, I just thought it is stupid. Thank you.

Comment: Consider using the [RAW Input API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645536.aspx) instead of a low-level mouse hook. You can then use  `SetWindowsLongPtr()`, `SetProp()`, or `SetWindowSubclass()` to associate your class object pointer with the HWND that receives `WM_INPUT` messages.